# How can I check if the user entered in an array is palindrome or not?

Tags: java, arrays, palindrome

I need help guys I have been checking on google for similar question but I cant find the most suitable answer for this. Here is my output.

```
Enter 3 Elements  
23
Is a palindrome  
22
Is not a palindrome  
11
Is not a palindrome
```

The program:

```
public static void main(String [] args)
{
  int number = 0;
  int reverse =0;
  int numCopy = 0; 
  Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to enter");
  int num = scan.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Enter "+num +" Elements");
  numCopy = num;          
  int[] array = new int[num];             
  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
  { 
    array[i] = scan.nextInt();
    int digit = numCopy % 10;
    numCopy = numCopy / 10;
    reverse = (reverse * 10) +digit;
    if(num == reverse)          
    {
      System.out.println("Is a palindrome");    
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Is not a palindrome");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Usually the concept of Palindrome is applied to strings.  Having said that, 22 and 11 would be a Palindrome (the number looks the same written forwards and backwards), and 23 would not be.  That is the opposite of what you state in your question.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

A Palindrome by definition is the same forwards and back so `11` would be and `22` would be. `23` would not etc.

Quick easy psudo code for checking if Palindrome as a STRING:

```
function isPalin(string str)
   if(str.length() == 0) {
     return true;
   }

   int end = str.length() - 1;
   int start = 0;
   while(start < end) {
     if(str[start++] != str[end--]) {
       return false;
     }
   }
   return true;
```

If you have numbers just covert it to a string then use the function.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem Seems like I had an issue with `end` str index. That should be fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

A palindrome, for example, we need to consider two difference case:
AA and ABA. 
These two are all palindrome. So for integers, you need to confirm its length is even or odd. Then check from both sides: start, end.

This should get the correct result.

Answer (score -1):

you should have your program like below:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
      int number = 0;
      int reverse =0;
      int numCopy = 0;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter how many numbers you want to enter");
      int num = scan.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Enter "+num +" Elements");
      numCopy = num;

String[] array = new String[num];   

for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{ 

    array[i] = new Integer(scan.nextInt()).toString();
    String rev="";
for(int k=array[i].length()-1;k>=0;k--){
    rev +=array[i].charAt(k);
}
    if(array[i].equals(rev))

    { 
        System.out.println("Is a palindrome");

    } 
    else 
        System.out.println("Is not a palindrome");
} 



}
```